# Result of $\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(\pi n)\sin(\pi n)$

Tags: limits

Task is to solve $\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(\pi n)\sin(\pi n)$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$ (**not** $n\in\Bbb R$). Is there any way to find definite solution?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is $n$ an integer? If yes, $\sin n\pi = 0$ for any $n$, so the limit is $0$.

Comment: Use the fact that $sinxcosx = \frac {sin2x}{2}$

Comment: @BadrB there is no need to use that formula for such a simple limit.

Comment: Thank you @Gibbs. Can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: @Gibbs That would be the case if $n$ is an integer, but I'm assuming it could be any real number as OP didn't specify. EDIT: Looks like I stand corrected, haha

Comment: @TomášSvoboda Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that

$$\sin (2x)=2\sin x \cos x$$

then we have that the expression

$$\cos(\pi n)\sin(\pi n)=\frac12 \sin(2\pi n)=\frac12 \sin (2\pi)=0$$

is identically zero and thus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(\pi n)\sin(\pi n)=0$$